# How do I update data in the service store in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I created a service where I declared the store:

**store.js:**

```
import Service from '@ember/service';

export default class StoreService extends Service {
  store = {
    lang: 'EN'
  }
}
```

I also got access to the store from the route:

**first.js:**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject } from '@ember/service';

export default Route.extend({
  store: inject(),
  model() {
    console.log(this.store);
    return this.store;
  }
});
```

And the template.
**first.hbs:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>First</h3>
  <hr class="gold">
  <p><button type="button">CN</button></p>
  {{model.store.lang}}
</div>

{{outlet}}
```

Please tell me how you can change the data in the store (set lang to "CN") from the route by pressing the "CN" button?

Regards.

Comment: what version of ember?

Comment: I'd highly recommend you use a different name aside from "store" since it's very misleading. I thought you were talking about Ember Data's store at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are usign ember >= 3.16. In your **store.js** track the state like

```
@tracked store = {
  lang: 'EN'
}
```

then in your **first.hbs** add to the button

`<button {{on "click" this.changeLanguajeToCN}} type="button">CN</button>`

and finally in your controller (you need to create this file) **first.js**

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class FirstController extends Controller {
  @service store;

  @action changeLanguajeToCN () {
    this.store.store = {...this.store, lang: 'CN'}
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on [Pablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64898802/1060660), I would recommend tracking the `lang` property itself rather than an object that contains it.

Also I would prefer to use a different name since `store` is misleading and people will assume you are trying to use [Ember Data's Store](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/release/classes/Store) which is available by default on Ember projects and as a property on routes.

See this Twiddle to see the code in action: 
https://ember-twiddle.com/02ac6f708d1861816df0f1bce504729a

```js
// app/services/settings.js

import Service from '@ember/service';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';

export default class SettingsService extends Service {
  @tracked lang = 'EN'
}
```

```js
// app/controllers/first.js

import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class FirstController extends Controller {
  @service settings;

  @action changeLanguajeToEN () {
    this.settings.lang = 'EN';
  }
  
  @action changeLanguajeToCN () {
    this.settings.lang = 'CN';
  }
}
```

```
{{! app/templates/first.hbs }}

<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>First route</h3>
  <hr class="gold">
  <p>
    <button type="button" {{on "click" this.changeLanguajeToEN}}>Change to English</button>
    <button type="button" {{on "click" this.changeLanguajeToCN}}>Change to Chinese</button>
  </p>
  <p>The current language is: <code>{{this.settings.lang}}</code></p>
</div>

{{outlet}}
```